# pg_upgrade with brew mac os 9.6.2 - 10.5

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-10, pg-upgrade

I've followed the excellent guide [here](https://blog.tafkas.net/2017/10/19/upgrading-postgresql-using-homebrew/) to upgrade from 9.6.2 to 10.5 on mac os 10.11.6. When I get to the step 6

```
pg_upgrade -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.2/bin/ \
-B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.5/bin/ \
-d /usr/local/Cellar/postgres.old/ \
-D /usr/local/Cellar/postgres.new/
```

I get this error

`check for "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.2/bin" failed: No such file or directory`

even though `mv /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.2 /usr/local/Cellar/postgres.old`  ran ok.

However when I go to

`/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.2/bin/: No such file or directory`

Looking at

```
$ du -sh /usr/local/var/*/
148K    /usr/local/var/homebrew/
917M    /usr/local/var/log/
202G    /usr/local/var/postgres96/
37M /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6/
```

I think my data is still there (postgres96) but don't understand how to get to it and finish `pg_upgrade`. Any help gratefully appreciated

EDIT;

I think i need to run something like the below to undo the error i made;

undo the move

```
mv /usr/local/Cellar/postgres.old /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.2
```

Check that worked running

```
ls /usr/local/Cellar/post*
```

I should see a bin in the 9.6.2 direcotry and then i can initialize a new cluster data dir:

```
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres.new
```

then

```
pg_upgrade -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.2/bin/ \
-B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.5/bin/ \
-d /usr/local/var/postgres96/ \
-D /usr/local/var/postgres.new/
```

Is that correct?

Given I've backed up with pg_dump

Comment: If you renamed postgresql to postgres.old postgresql/bin is now postgres.old/bin. HTH :-)

Comment: The error says that path doesn’t exist. And if you say you moved the files away from there that’s probably the reason. Why are you telling it to use nonexistent paths on the command line?

Comment: @kometen Thanks for the hint but it doesn't think that's there either `check for "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql.old/bin" failed: No such file or directory
`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen those are the steps listed on that blog, I'm not familiar with the command line

Comment: @mappingdom What folders do you see if you issue a 'ls /usr/local/Cellar/post*'?

Comment: @kometen thanks i see `/usr/local/Cellar/postgres.old:
COPYRIGHT   README    include
HISTORY    bin    lib
INSTALL_RECEIPT.json  homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist share` but swapping that into pg_upgrade still get `could not open version file: /usr/local/Cellar/postgres.old/PG_VERSION
`

Comment: @mappingdom Did you mistakenly rename the folder in /usr/local/Cellar rather than /usr/local/var? The guide only rename (mv) /usr/local/var.

Comment: @kometen i've edited the original Q with what i think i now need to run – will i need 202gb free on the drive to run this given thats the size of existing postgres96 ordoes it just rename/replace links